# What is a head in Coq head normal form?

Tags: coq

I am having trouble understanding Coq/CIC head normal form. More specifically, I don't understand what is a head. The reference manual (8.5p1) says that

> Any term can be written as:

[image: hnf]

But the above definition is in the negative sense: it requires `t0` not to be an application, but didn't say what **can** `t0` be. In fact, as far as I can remember, the only thing that can be written as `t0 t1 t2 ...` **is** an application of a function or constructor `t0`.

Can someone help spell out what  exactly can be the head here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `t0 t1 ... tn` is an application, but the manual is talking about the form of `t0` standing by itself.

In the manual, `t` or `ti` for some `i` usually denotes a *term*, so `t0` can be any term, that is not an application, e.g. a λ-abstraction, etc. -- see the list in [sect. 4.1.2](https://coq.inria.fr/doc/Reference-Manual006.html#Terms) of the manual and the [sect. 1.2.1](https://coq.inria.fr/doc/Reference-Manual003.html#term) on syntax.

Also, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_normal_form) Wikipedia page might be of some help.

Comment: You write that `t0` can be a lambda-abstraction, but in this case this would not be a normal form, as a `t0 t1` would be a beta-redex.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. But neither the manual nor I don't say it *is* in normal form. Check section [4.4](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual006.html#subtyping-rules), subsection "Normal form". The question comes from the OP's try to work through it.